# sftpclone command not working as a cronjob

Tags: cron

I am struggling to get a simple cronjob running sftpclone working.

Details:

I can access the SFTP server via SSH key, i.e.:

```
# sftp username@my.backup.server.com
```

results in immediate access to the command line of the server.

I can also perform a successful backup via the command:

```
# sftpclone /var/mytest/ username@my.backup.server.com:test
```

But the same command doesn't seem to work if included in a cronjob. I tried adding a simple cronjob (i.e. with the command as in the example above), and I kept adding more details, such as the explicit user (root) and the location of the key to use. The final job is:

```
*/10   *   *   *   *   root   /usr/local/bin/sftpclone /var/mytest/ username@my.backup.server.com:test -k /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And it still doesn't work. I am unsure as to how to troubleshoot the problem. Other cronjobs work fine, and the same command works perfectly in the command line:

```
/usr/local/bin/sftpclone /var/mytest/ username@my.backup.server.com:test -k /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Troubleshooting: the [Cron tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) is excellent!

Comment: Thanks, @BenjaminW. I used that post for the initial configuration but I went through all the steps again and I realised that I made a mistake by adding the user. In the beginning, I was not including the user, but I was not specifying the key either. So the real solution to the problem was adding the key with the option -k, which is not needed when sending the command manually.